# VBA Unable to copy chart on specific worksheet to PowerPoint

Tags: excel, vba, charts, powerpoint

I have multiple sheets with charts but I would like to copy charts from "Calculated Sheets" only, but my code is failing. If I don't put the `("Calculated Sheets")`, the macro copies all the charts. Thanks for the help.

```
Dim ppt As PowerPoint.Application
Dim ppTPres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim pptSld As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim pptCL As PowerPoint.CustomLayout
Dim pptShp As PowerPoint.Shape

Dim chtt As Chart
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim i As Long

'Optimise execution of code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Get the PowerPoint Application object:
Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
ppt.Visible = msoTrue
Set ppTPres = ppt.Presentations.Add

'Get a Custom Layout:
For Each pptCL In ppTPres.SlideMaster.CustomLayouts
    If pptCL.Name = "Title and Content" Then Exit For
Next pptCL

For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculated Values")
    For i = 1 To ws.ChartObjects.Count
        Set pptSld = ppTPres.Slides.AddSlide(ppTPres.Slides.Count + 1, pptCL)
        pptSld.Select

        For Each pptShp In pptSld.Shapes.Placeholders
            If pptShp.PlaceholderFormat.Type = ppPlaceholderObject Then Exit For
        Next pptShp

        Set chtt = ws.ChartObjects(i).Chart
        chtt.ChartArea.Copy
        ppt.Activate
        pptShp.Select
        ppt.Windows(1).View.Paste

          Next i
           Next ws
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I would like to copy charts from "Calculated Sheets" only

If you need chart only from a specific sheet then why the loop `For Each ws In ActiveWorkbook`

Directly work with the worksheet. Remove the above for loop.

```
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Calculated Values")

For i = 1 To ws.ChartObjects.Count
    '
    '~~> Rest of your code
    '
Next i
```